# Enviar variables por $_POST en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy realizando un módulo para un sitio en wordpress y necesito enviar datos de un formulario a otro archivo PHP, pero si intento realizarlo de la manera tradicional no recibo las variables por $POST

(este es mi formulario)

```
  <form id="formRespuesta" method="POST" action="http://localhost/refaplaza/action/">
        <div><b>Te realizaron la siguiente pregunta: </b></div>
        <div id="pregunta"></div><br>
        <div><b>Respuesta Max. 250 caracteres</b></div>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="60" maxlength="250" id="answer" name="answer"></textarea><br></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Responder</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </form>
```

(archivo a donde envío las variables)

```
$answer= $_POST["answer"];

/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 * Template Name: action
 * @package _bootstraps
 * @package _bootstraps - 2013 1.0
*/

get_header();


?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-9">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php 

        echo "answer= ".$answer."<br>";

        ?>

    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Pero Cuando intento imprimir la variable `$answer` no me trae nada, como si el método $POST no funcionara

¿Alguna idea de como puedo enviar las variables del formulario por $POST?

Comment: Puedes mostrar algún código de lo que estas intentando hacer ? tu pregunta no es clara de tus objetivos.

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]** para que sepas como formular preguntas que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad !

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta e incluí código

Comment: @L.Diaz te saca algún error o simplemente te envía la variable vacía ?

Comment: solamente me la envía vacía, pero si  envío las variables por `$GET` si las recibe

Answer (score 2):

No estas especificando el nombre del archivo php al que lo estas enviando.

Por ejemplo:

```
 action="http://localhost/refaplaza/action/xxxx.php">
```

Revisa como trabajar con formularios.
http://php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: 1. la página action es la que tiene el php, así que si estoy especificando

Comment: Debe ser como comenta Diego, el nombre del archivo y la extensión PHP. **xxxx.php**

Comment: si lo hago de esa forma wordpress me marca un error 404 por eso incruste el codigo php en una página de wordpress

Comment: Prueba: if (isset($_POST["answer"]){ echo "ok"; }                                                             Con esto podrás constatar el estado de la variable. y estoy viendo que tu código    echo "answer= ".$answer."<br>"; cuando tendrías que usar siempre el $_POST["answer"] para obtener el valor